# use parameters from python launch file in node

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use parameters specified in my .launch.py file, but a ParameterNotDeclaredException is thrown when accessing any parameter. Does anyone know why? I try to access the parameters like this from within my Node:

```
self.get_parameter('buffer_size')
```

Here is the launch file. I'm using Foxy and Python

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='blackfly_calibration',
            executable='broadcaster',
            parameters=[
                {"capture_frequency": 20.0},
                {"buffer_size": 10},
                {"image_topic": "/camera/image_raw"}
            ],
        )
    ])
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384463/use-parameters-from-python-launch-file-in-node/) by [rosnoob145](https://answers.ros.org/users/81280/rosnoob145/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before calling get_parameter, you had need to call;

```
self.declare_parameter(“buffer_size”,0)
```

Here you initialize buffer_size with a default value of 0, you can set a desired default parameter.

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2021-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosnoob145](https://answers.ros.org/users/81280/rosnoob145/) on 2021-08-16**:
thank you so much!